# How to turn time series padding into a function in R and run it on a list

Tags: r, function, time-series, lapply

I am new to using R.

I have a data frame which has dates and a list of counties and another target variable "t". I split the dataframe into a list of dataframes using the split function. Now i need to pad each data frame in the list with the missing dates and value of zero for the target "t".

I tried creating a function first and then using lapply. I am new to creating functions so i guess there might be an error in how i am creating the function.

```
    funct<- function(nn){
    sorted<-nn[order(nn$ds),]
    min <- min(sorted$ds)
    max <- max(sorted$ds)
    dates <- seq(min, max, by="day")
    frame<-data.frame(list(ds=dates))
    merged<-merge(x=frame,y=sorted,by="ds",all.x=TRUE)
    merged$t[which(is.na(merged$t))] <- 0
    return(nn)}

    out <- split( test , f = test$COUNTY_ST ) 

    z<-lapply(out,funct )
```

Here is the data

```
    ds          t   COUNTY_ST
    2011-01-28  1   la
    2011-01-30  4   la
    2011-01-28  1   mm
    2011-01-30  4   mm
```

Comment: Are you open for alternative functions? Check out the [`padr` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/padr/vignettes/padr.html).

Comment: I made it work. I was returning the argument input instead of the final merged variable. I took a look at padR too.